# Account for two different function variations in Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-types

I'm unsure how to properly type a function passed as props.

It can basically have two shapes:

```
// Hoc1.tsx
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

const Hoc1 = () => {
  const cancelResponse = async (agreement: boolean) => {
    return mockCall(agreement);
  };

  return <ChildComponent cancelResponse={cancelResponse} />;
};

export default Hoc1;
```

and

```
// Hoc2.tsx
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

const Hoc2 = () => {
  const cancelResponse = async (data: {
    agreement: boolean;
    shiftId: string;
    userId: string;
  }) => {
    return mockCall(data);
  };

  return (
    <ChildComponent
      cancelResponse={cancelResponse}
      cancelData={{ shiftId: "1", userId: "2" }}
    />
  );
};

export default Hoc2;
```

Now I'm unsure, how I should go about properly typing this. I tried using a conditional

These two pass different functions to the said ChildComponent

```
type CancelResponseVariant<ArgumentVariant> = ArgumentVariant extends boolean
  ? boolean
  : { agreement: boolean; shiftId: string; userId: string };

type Props = {
  cancelResponse: <T>(arg: CancelResponseVariant<T>) => Promise<void>;
  cancelData?: { shiftId: string; userId: string };
};

const ChildComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const { cancelData, cancelResponse } = props;
  const onCancelResponse = async (agreement: boolean) => {
    if (cancelData) {
      await cancelResponse({ agreement, ...cancelData });
    } else {
      await cancelResponse(agreement);
    }
  };

  return <button onClick={async () => onCancelResponse(true)}>Example</button>;
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

This seems to be nearing the solution, however is not quite it. The last call produces the following error:

> Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ agreement: boolean; shiftId: string; userId: string; }'.ts(2345)

And in the HoC passing the function produces the following error:

> Type '(agreement: boolean) => Promise' is not assignable to type '(arg: CancelResponseVariant) => Promise'.
> Types of parameters 'agreement' and 'arg' are incompatible.
> Type 'CancelResponseVariant' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
> Type 'boolean | { agreement: boolean; shiftId: string; userId: string; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
> Type '{ agreement: boolean; shiftId: string; userId: string; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Any idea how I should go about properly typing this?

> Note: Obviously I tried using a simple conditional union type as well
>
> ```
> type Data = { agreement: boolean, userId: string, shiftId: string }
> type Props = {
>   (agreement: boolean | Data) => Promise<void>
> }
> ```
>
> but that still throws an error inside the HoC

You can see the error reproduced here:

[image: Edit practical-leaf-s1hx8d]

or [TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWONCAOwGd4QI0BrAYRQBte4AXjgomATwZo4ACgAmKGCgBcIhmICUQgHxwA3qThwiMAK5QGcBkgDucAAo4QwJkmnTMmwTpcwAKqCQIExh3ABo4AEYABhj1dQBuUgBfRNIAegAqOABaXLz8uC4AC2BeWS5cSCsGeHy63LgMtNIYMTAkQpRJJF5kJiqXADUUKGAumAAeAEEoAHMTECQa4dHxnWEZ+cXlkbGauCoYJdkmOAAjCAheVAYDOAB+c8vrrruVXRFZoiRtmBULq43eJwJglTAwACSshULFGDFmwJMLigUJhMDhszgKXIrXa9hwYFOwn0hjQXTQPT6AyQKgmvi00hGsxUPG6vSQ-UYQ124zpWk8OgcuGcSAmADcIMBZFpEqTyT0ACIKFD3d4gsGQ6Eg9HAeGI5Go7UYrGJbGkejMeDFUrlSqMJbwYTSMAEpgqIWEgV6O4Wlh6Ojy3hKxThMlsqlcjpJIRwF0QQmyuhc+CMVkU9mc5gdYSiCRSRlfJA-B3-Z43L0kwxwYCYGRh9PBlCaStVkTWFDAeD1ykc6nSD4oQvFmrhAB04+7QeVWISd0M0Z6Lm9rcMKHbnYD4d7kYL31+s9bSTuZsMxjMFgmZ2CMEYcFTvGAnEEulzkhkXtTgYjWek6JMSHUJItAAUUoFBwGuCY0ivGAbwYGVklSTIcnqPI4AACXYCIUNQhomnNZMMKwmNpArH1CMnb8lxzcQ313ItflLQEujI1sz3MOA2E4Hh+Ho4cYAPE1yFPJBTA4iZrTKCpwHtfZKO3LNn3kzMXGjNIELNZDcIaTC0AAJhw3DGmaX14F0gynVYpNLU3dMqOzERaPzeRFHeOdPj3EsnmYhhE0MUEa01NEMT8uAkSQFEtVhXUEWPKyRLEiwuO4PheDkZVBJPIxRPPGR3IkkopLtaoYHcuUtxUpAlK-BTVLK2zFWVZ8PgC8FDQAIgidrwnCyKVHavT2qxI9W3Uu5ZxSIA)

*PS: I am aware this is not the ideal way to pass the functions with different arg variations, but it's a 5 year old codebase that I need to migrate to typescript, so for now, I'm just working with what I can.*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The latter. They are two completely different function variations depending on from which HoC the `cancelResponse` prop is passed. And yes, your assumption about the `cancelData` being the only differntiative factor is correct

Comment: Thanks for the updates to the question, that really helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `cancelData` in the props alongside `cancelResponse`, you have a discriminated union (even when the HOC doesn't provide a `cancelData` property), so you can define `Props` like this:

```typescript
type Props =
    // First variant
    {
        cancelResponse: (arg: boolean) => Promise<unknown>;
        cancelData?: never;
    }
    |
    // Second variant
    {
        cancelResponse: (arg: { agreement: boolean; shiftId: string; userId: string }) => Promise<unknown>;
        cancelData: { shiftId: string; userId: string };
    };
```

*(I'll explain about `Promise<unknown>` instead of `Promise<void>` in a moment, you probably don't need to make that change in your real code, but I did for the example.)*

We need `cancelData?: never;` in the first variant because without it, we don't have a fully discriminated union. But we make it optional so HOCs that don't need it don't provide it (and thus use the simple `(agreement: boolean) => Promise<unknown>` signature).

`ChildComponent` figures out which call to make based on `cancelData`:

```typescript
const ChildComponent = (props: Props) => {
    const onCancelResponse = async (agreement: boolean) => {
        if (props.cancelData) {
            await props.cancelResponse({ agreement, ...props.cancelData });
        } else {
            await props.cancelResponse(agreement);
        }
    };

    return <button onClick={async () => onCancelResponse(true)}>Example</button>;
};
```

That makes both `Hoc1` and `Hoc2` work, and disallows this incorrect `Hoc3`:

```typescript
// With an intentional error
const Hoc3 = () => {
    const cancelResponse = async (agreement: boolean) => {
        return mockCall(agreement);
    };

    return <ChildComponent cancelResponse={cancelResponse} cancelData={{shiftId: "1", userId: "2"}} />;
    //      ^−−−−− Error as desired, the provided `cancelResponse` has the wrong signature
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWONCAOwGd4QI0BrAYRQBte4AXjgomATwZo4ACgAmKGCgBcIhmICUQgHxwA3qTiG4RGAFcoDOAyQB3OAAUcIYEyTTpmTYJ2uYAFVAkCFMYDwAaOABGAAZY9XUAblIAXyTSAHoAKjgAWjz8grguAAtgXlkuXEhrBngC+ry4TPTyGDEwJAccMCYhAyN09LgAMWAoFjgANxQoYBRa-sN9IxW6ebQkXmQmatcVaRmAcxUAIwgIXlQGLx1HXBckAB5TBg4GCBsGLSTVozR1zYAEQUKAA-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-3o5MP3kQ0KJXPcROzdkGEdVZuULU0ZTlQKVglaFbWFS0xQRRVyOXIwpN49huD4Xg5BrQLT0kpAzB46Q5zgR4ZM9eSahgEqdR-ZzVN0Jzuz-Y96z+ScDRQF9aWC3lbQAIkifqIiiqUzX64z+oVVrfh0hFZz0syGmItAAGYluWgjUQAdRbYpVDgS0YB9YBGD4BcoBwKBCIclb1tspLKNupqKVc99Ux8li2P8uzflSviMsE-thJ9MSnQklKCovUryrk6ofSUztmoal6ey06jOu63rQrgQbhrgUaBsm5ItJ0wLUVWAA9QAkIlp2m4FAy7oCTOBZC7MYkFkCIYGKToS0mYA2ZxAADVG-2FuBilEOAec6GwcFFLlgEOBgFHMJAUiSIA)

About `Promise<unknown>` rather than `Promise<void>` in the example: That's because in `Hoc1` and `Hoc2`, your code was doing `return mockCall(agreement);` and `mockCall` didn't have a return type annotation so ends up with `Promise<unknown>`. You may not need that change, if the actual calls HOCs make do have the return type `Promise<void>`. If they do, you're good to go with your original `Promise<void>`, [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWONCAOwGd4QI0BrAYRQBte4AXjgomATwZo4ACgAmKGCgBcIhmICUQgHxwA3qTiGRAdxTB4DJMbgAFHCGBMk06Zk2CdTmABVQSCACuMK4ANHAAjAAM0erqANykAL4JpAD0AFRwALQ5uXlwXAAWwLyyXLiQlgzwebU5cOmp5DBiYEi2OGBMQgZGqalwAGLAUCxwAG4oUMAo1b2G+kZLdLNoSLzITJVOKtJTAOYqAEYQELyoDO46driOSAA84xDAsloJy0Zoq+sAIgooAH4VJZxkgoO8jIl5nAAD7Q-pwADKSHoDFkEymMzmS0WHxWknWm22SF2BxUuhE+yISBASGqx1O51mcTgTGKmBgAElZCoWNMGPsWQEnFBubyYPz9nBElcOrcnI9nq8IR8vgTeH9FOTWeyuTzWRLgAKhSKxQbJdKVZbyKixkUSmUKow6fBhNIwJ0mCobl1ZbjDLb4IweOqiYwnEIROJJDIUFSkDSXQyzhc-dClsBMDIPRAugA6NVrDX-TT+vGGFCmcxwHP5wuEpBbcPOClx6m06phPPd2tMAvfYuKaXxdOQuDrCNl8uVszwXv90ON4l7eOJ6oj8tQpbJchLIgwAJQBhwe5HIIwRhwYO8YCcQS6UQSKTSWXBgdh5jOCUBJDqRJaABRSgUHAc57lSM8YAvBg3iSFIMmyOpcjgAAJdhwkQpD6kaUhA1Q9DIxfbQ9GhPD6w2Jdm0jR8YxXdskzgE4U1mNNy33Q9jzYTgeH4OiEw7GAN0hFI9yQA8jxPe1SnKcBnWqfEiw-Jx73IpSkESOBUlgnc0kyLD6jQtAACZMKwhomjwwyTLdVjPnDeBVMoz9qOjZ95C1Ejp1XATkyZBgrSWNlMz1cVJQCoxhTBM0+SNQVoRlYipyMdiJK47g+F4OQSytHTRPE49pFHQx7ikx1ZKqGAiuWRym0-FT3ycpwt3LT4B01FB7wpIKOTNAAicJerCSLRX1XqjN66Vmo+LToRHHSEP0rJ8LQABmUykPMtIBgAdXMQpVDgI0YBdYBGD4ccoBwKBcPs5a1psxLSNumriRcp9Y28himL82yPhSzj2HS3i234l0hMMXLkrEjjJOKaSnQqhSG1q5TdBe5sNPI9rOu6kK4H6wa4GGvrxsSDStKtBFlgAPUAJCJ6fpuAAMu6AozgWRGxGJBZDCGBCnaHNxhebm4AAA3Rz9RbgQpRDgPn2mMHABVZYB9gYBRDyQODSCAA).

Comment: Would `cancelData: undefined` be functionally the same as ` cancelData?: never;` for the first variant?

Comment: @PIG208 - It would be close, but would allow code using `ChildComponent` to do `<ChildComponent cancelResponse={cancelResponse} cancelData={undefined} />` (see `Hoc4` [here](https://tsplay.dev/w24Vjm)) which is confusing (to me). But yes, very nearly the same thing. I like `never` because (I think??) you can't actually supply it.